# prove $\det(adj{A})=\det(A)$ for any $A\in{M}_{n\times{n}}$

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, determinant

I'm using the book "linear algebra" by Hoffman and Kunze as I'm preparing to a test on the course "linear algebra" in university. 
I couldn't find answers to the exercises presented in the book. 
one of the exercises is:

> prove: $\det(\operatorname{adj}{A})=\det(A)$ for any $A\in{M}_{n\times{n}}$

I have never heard of this claim (which is odd as this one might be very useful).

I **don't** want to prove this using the following method :
let $A=a_{ij}$, as I'd want to find an expression for $\det(A)$ using $a_{ij}$ and the minors of $A$, and to do the same for  $\operatorname{adj}A$. this is probably the worst way try to prove such question, without even me knowing it will work.

this is a problem as I would like to have more intuition about time-wasting methods (and might even just Wrong) to make proofs in a test.

Comment: What is $\text{adj } A$ in this book? If it's what I think of as $\text{adj } A$  then this is not true.

Comment: Are you sure it is "adjacency matrix" and not "[adjugate matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Adjugate_matrix)"? (It is still not true for the latter as the previous comment states except $2\times 2$ case).

Comment: your'e right, fixed it

Comment: if $A=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{11} & a_{12}\\
a_{21} & a_{22}
\end{array}\right],$ 
$adjA=\left[\begin{array}{cc}
a_{22} & -a_{12}\\
-a_{21} & a_{11}
\end{array}\right]$

Comment: Then $\det(\operatorname{adj}{A})=\det(A)^{\color{red}{n-1}}$ (see Properties in the link above).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think the problem in Section 5.2 of the book is for the case $n=2$. The result is not valid for other values of $n$. For $n=2$ we have $A (adj A)=det(A) I$ Take determinants and use the fact that $det (AB)=det (A) det(B)$ to get $det (A) det (adj (A))=(det(A)) ^{2}$. This gives $det (adj (A))=det (A)$ at least when $det (A) \neq 0$. When $det (A)=0$ you can approximate $A$ by $A+c_nI$ with $c_n \to 0$ and $A+c_nI$ invertible for all $n$.